# Import Blog Posts into Mailchimp as a new Automation Campaign

Tags: mailchimp

I've recently encountered Mailchimp automation campaigns.

I have 357 pieces of Wordpress content I'd like to import into a Mailchimp automation campaign, to be sent 1 per week.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, this can definitely be done!

See here:

> https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/blog-posts-in-campaigns/share-your-blog-posts-with-mailchimp

Basically MailChimp will take the RSS feed of your WordPress blog, check for updates once every day, week or month and then send if there is anything new.

Comment: @Steve No problem! Don't forget to upvote if it helped ;) I'm actually using this right now on my blog (https://codetheweb.blog)